# Applying distHaversine and generating the minimum output

Tags: r

I have two dataframes. One containing the customer's ip address and the other containing store's location.

I would like to generate the distance(using distHaversine) from a customer's ip address to the closest store's location. I imagine applying dishaversine to the customer's lat and long against each store's lat and long, and then using which.min to output the smallest output.

Below is a snapshot of how much data looks like.

```
    customer_data
customer_id lat long 
1 50 33
2 44 -21
3 129 -22


    store_data
store lat long
1 33 22
2 -111 -139
3 23 30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31668415/3460670) was helpful in looking at potential solutions.

The first step would be to create a distance matrix with `distm` based on both of your data frames. You can select `distHaversine` method if you wish, with others available.

Then you can determine with store is closest for each customer by `max.col` (negative sign before `mat` will check for value that is least negative).

You can also add the distance from the matrix (here in meters).

I made up some example data from U.S. and changed store to A, B, C for clarity in answer.

```
library(geosphere)

# create a distance matrix
mat <- distm(customer_data[,c('long','lat')], store_data[,c('long','lat')], fun=distHaversine)

# assign the store name to customer_data based on shortest distance in the matrix
customer_data$locality <- store_data$store[max.col(-mat)]

# add distance in km for that store
customer_data$nearest_dist <- apply(mat, 1, min)/1000
```

**Output**

```
  customer_id  lat  long locality nearest_dist
1           1 41.8  87.6        A     313.5497
2           2 40.7  74.0        B     440.4867
3           3 36.8 119.4        C     784.7909
```

**Data**

```
customer_data <- data.frame(
  customer_id = c(1, 2, 3),
  lat = c(41.8, 40.7, 36.8),
  long = c(87.6, 74, 119.4)
)

store_data <- data.frame(
  store = c("A", "B", "C"),
  lat = c(44.5, 44.5, 43.8),
  long = c(88.7, 72.5, 120.5)
)
```

Comment: I have tried to replicate the effort. My R session would abort after a minute though...
My two dataframes contain 689k rows and 26k rows.

Comment: Ah, I see - I didn't realize that. There are number of other answers related to calculating large distance matrices (or other approaches to find closest distance with multi-k rows of points). Perhaps one of these might be helpful: [distm with big memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44313983/r-distm-with-big-memory), or [distm for big data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49863185/r-distm-for-big-data-calculating-minimum-distances-between-two-matrices)

Comment: Also might take a look at this referenced [blog post](https://privefl.github.io/blog/performance-when-algorithmics-meets-mathematics/).